Finding all $k$ for which $\frac{x^2+k^2}{k(6+x)}\ge1$ for all $x$ such that $-1\le x \le 1$

Find all values of $k$ for which the inequality $$\frac{x^2+k^2}{k(6+x)}\ge1$$ is satisfied for all $x$ such that $-1\le x \le 1$.

Since the numerator is always positive, and $(6+x) \in [5,7]$ on $[-1,1]$ , it can be deduced that $k>0.$
Subtracting 1 on both sides gives: $$\frac{x^2-kx+k^2-6k}{k\left(6+x\right)} \ge 0.$$
The numerator's discriminant $3k\left(8-k\right)$ is
Negative: for $k<0 \;\text{and} \;k>8$  from previous calculations, we restrict the interval to $k>8$ only.
Zero: for $k=0$ the inequality is indeterminate  $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$for $k=8$ we have $\frac{(x-4)^2}{8\left(6+x\right)}\ge0$ which is true on $[-1,1].$
Positive: for $0<k<8.$
Now I'm left with the tougher part, where discriminant is positive ($0<k<8$). This is the part that is causing me some trouble.

Discriminant is positive indicates $f(x)$ is negative between the two roots. Are the two roots both less or more than $(-1,1)$?

@Gwen The two roots would be $\frac{k-\sqrt{3k\left(8-k\right)}}{2}$ and $\frac{k+\sqrt{3k\left(8-k\right)}}{2}$. Now I can't say for sure whether both the roots would be less or more than (-1,1).



Find all values of $k$ for which the inequality $\dfrac{x^2+k^2}{k(6+x)}\ge1$ is satisfied for all $x$ such that $-1\le x \le 1.$


To phrase it better: we want all the values of $k$ for which $$\forall x{\in}[-1,1]\, \dfrac{x^2+k^2}{k(6+x)}\ge1,$$ that is (since, by inspection, the denominator must be positive), $$\forall x{\in}[-1,1]\: x^2-kx+k^2-6k\ge0.$$
This corresponds to the union of these three cases:

non-positive discriminant
$k\ge8$




left $\boldsymbol x$-intercept $\boldsymbol {\ge1}$
$\frac12(7+3\sqrt5)\le k\le8$

right $\boldsymbol x$-intercept $\boldsymbol {\le-1}$
$k$ doesn't exist.


Therefore, the required set is $$\left[\frac12(7+3\sqrt5),\infty\right).$$

I'm sorry, I don't understand. How did you calculate the left and right x-intercepts?

@dev Using the quadratic formula, aren't the two intercepts just $\frac{k\pm\sqrt{k^2-4(k^2-6k)}}2$ ? Okay, I've just expanded the answer to illustrate cases #2 and #3 and add links to their computations.

Another way: you need to find for what positive $k$ would $k^2-6k \geqslant x(k-x)$ hold true for all $|x|\leqslant 1$.
As this has to hold true for $x=0$, trivially, we need $k^2-6k\geqslant0 \implies k\geqslant6$.
For such $k$, the quadratic (in $x$) RHS is maximised at the boundary, i.e. when $x=1$, so it is enough to solve for this case: $k^2-6k\geqslant k-1 \implies (k-\frac72)^2 \geqslant \frac{49}4-1=\frac{45}4 \implies k\geqslant \frac72+\frac{\sqrt{45}}2$.

You can reverse thinking a bit for $0<k<8$.
Let $k$ be real and ask when $x=\pm 1$ would be roots of the numerator function.  When $x=-1$, you have  $1+k^2-5k = 0 $ or $k \simeq 4.8$. This tells you that starting with $k =5$, for some range $x \in [-1, -1 + \epsilon]$ your inequality will hold. Now if this is to be true for the full interval $[-1 1]$, check   whether  $x= 1$ would be root of the numerator function. You have  $1+k^2-7k = 0 $ or $k \simeq 6.8$. So indeed, only for $k=7$ the inequality holds in the range $0<k<8$.
